# Public REST service and AngularJS single page application

Tags: angularjs, rest, security, single-page-application

currently I'm developing a single page application based on angularJS. How can I prevent call to public rest service from outside my webapp? Is this a real concern?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You should implement authentication on your REST server/provider and application. This can be done in serveral ways but my recommendation is [OAUTH 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) over [https](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperText_Transfer_Protocol_Secure).

Comment: but the api is public (e.g. search api), there is no restriction. My concern is that the search service could be call from outside the angular app.

Comment: There are four different [grant types](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/grant-types/).  It is possible to allow a certain app access to resources on behalf of somebody else. Is there a reason why you only want to shield your public api?